# How do I generate a csv file for charts?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to generate a data.csv file based on my database. For example, once an hour the file will generate new data from the database or in real time.

I made a sample code, but it doesn't work properly. It saves the following line 1701873011211,[object Promise] to a file, and only when accessing the router.

```
admin.get('/chart', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = db.manager.findAndCount(User)
    let entry = "";
    let fileData = "";

    entry = Date.now() + "," + users + ","
    fileData += "\n" + entry;

    fs.writeFile(path.join("assets/data.csv"),
      fileData,
      function (err: any, data: any) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return res.redirect("back");
        }
        return fs.readFileSync(path.join("assets/data.csv"));
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})
```

I need to receive a string in this format
`2023-12-06,250,207,8912`
Date, users per day, articles per day, comments per day

Comment: `Date.now()` returns milliseconds since epoch, [as documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now). `[object Promise]` means you received a promise for a future value and tried to turn it directly into a string. You'll need to figure out how to wait for the promise to resolve and then to retrieve the results from the promise (usually via `await` or `.then()`). After that, you'll need to figure out how to extract the data you want from the returned results (just converting `users` to a string isn't going to do that).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have at least two problems:

1. You don't handle the `Promise` returned by `db.manager.findAndCount(User)`.
2. You aren't formatting the `Date` object correctly.

---

## Problem 1

If you aren't familiar with handling `Promise`s in JavaScript (or TypeScript), I highly suggest reading [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

You already declared the callback to `admin.get` as `async`, so you can just add an `await` before `db.manager.findAndCount(User)`; code execution will pause at that line until the `Promise` resolves or rejects. This means that the rest of the code will run with the actual value of `users` *or* the `catch` statement will run if the `Promise` rejects.

## Problem 2

`Date.now()` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC, hence why you're getting that large number instead of the formatted date.

See the MDN documentation for more on `Date`; you can use the following to format the date roughly how you want:

```js
const now = new Date();
const formattedDate = `${now.getFullYear()}-${now.getMonth()}-${now.getDay()}
```

See [this TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUBcCcEsDsDmsBmBPBjQBECGkBTAOngHsB3ACgEoAoAY1PgGdSAbYt0xSvQkijTq0QEGJlQYkoeAXI58BGgyasORLj1ny+S6sNEBhUtGgF6kUChMBbfJEwqWlsvIC8MuQsI0A3E+ZLa2g7SEIAE11QDwADABIAb1ciRAJIADEAVzY2AE0CXGgaAF8AWkTk1MgAWSZIAAsS8qSKFLS8NBKYgPZObkpg0IjdaiA) for an example.